# rendering a PDF when the file is in the static folder by passing filename through render_template to html page

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['post'])
def upload():
    global des2,des,filenam,lis
    target = os.path.join(APP_ROOT,'static')

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    fi = request.files['file']
    filenam = secure_filename(fi.filename)
    des = "\ ".join([target,filenam])
    fi.save(des)
    fi.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filenam))
    pdftotext.readfile(des)
    lis = check.listreturn()
    return render_template('pdfembed.html',filename1=filenam)
```

pdfembed.html

const url = "./{{ filename1 }}";
.........

pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(pdfDoc_ =>{

I'm rendering PDF file present in static folder into canvas using pdfjs by sending filename from flask file to html file.But it is not rendering.How will i change the way give input to html file.

Comment: Please show some code samples.

Comment: Can you elaborate on it's not rendering portion? Is there any error?